# Randomizing Initial Conditions of NDSolve Differential Equation Phase Space Plots with Looping Structures

Tags: differential-equations, procedural-programming

I am looking for a way to randomize the initial conditions on the numerical approximation for the angular displacement of a plane pendulum. I have been trying for hours, and believe a For loop is easiest, but I don't know how to get it to work.

My objective is to produce 10 total phase plots, overlaid on each other, of different initial conditions with 5 of the plots of `θ_0` between (`-π` and `π`) and 5 plots of `θ_0` outside of (`-π` and `π`).

When I run this, I get a list of plot[11] and then some broken/wierd stuff that aren't nicely overlaid on plot[11].

#### Edit

It appears an `ic2a/b` value of +/- 5 is too large. Sometimes the initial conditions break the orbits.

#### Edit 2

I forgot to define g and R. Fixed.

#### Edit 3

Fixed the code. See comments below for diagnosis and steps to solution. Thanks for the help. RandomColor still doesn't manifest in the plots, but it's superficial (as is a legend) in this situation. Also I haven't had a phase plot to be shifted from the origin along the [Theta] axis. I still consider the issue solved because I have my plots and am at least able to generate random values for the initial conditions.

```
g=9.8;
R=1;
SeedRandom[RandomInteger[100]]; (*sets a random seed to generate below RandomReal's*)


Array[plot, 11];

plot[11] = 
   Plot[f[x], {x, -100, 100}, 
     PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {-20, 20}}, 
     Frame -> True, 
     FrameLabel -> 
       {"Displacement, θ", Row[{"Momentum, ", Subscript[P, θ]}]}, 
     PlotLabel -> 
       "Phase Space of Approoximate Motion of A Vertical Plane Pendelum", 
     ImageSize -> Large];

For[i = 1, i < 11, i++,
  If[i < 6,
    ic1a = RandomReal[{-π, π}];
      (*5 initial condition displacements between-π and π*)
    ic2a = RandomReal[{-5, 5}];
      (*initial condition momentum=random number between-5 and 5*)
    theta =
      NDSolve[
        {x''[t] == -(g/R) Sin[x[t]], x[0] == ic1a, x'[0] == ic2a}, 
        x, {t, 0, 15},
       MaxSteps -> 20000];
    plot[i] =
      ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], Derivative[1][x][t]} /. theta], {t, 0, 10},
        AspectRatio -> 1,
        PlotLabel -> Style["Phase Space"],
        AxesLabel -> {"θ", "θ'"},
        PlotStyle -> RandomColor];,
    (*else,i.e.i≥6*)
    ic1b = RandomReal[{π, -π}];
       (*5 initial condition displacements outside of-π and π*)
    ic2b = RandomReal[{-5, 5}]; 
      (*initial condition momentum=random number between-5 and 5*)
    theta =
      NDSolve[
        {x''[t] == -(g/R) Sin[x[t]], x[0] == -(ic1b), x'[0] == ic2b}, 
        x, {t, 0, 15},
        MaxSteps -> 20000];
    plot[i] =
      ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], Derivative[1][x][t]} /. theta], {t, 0, 10},
        AspectRatio -> 1,
        PlotLabel -> Style["Phase Space"],
        AxesLabel -> {"θ", "θ'"},
        PlotStyle -> RandomColor];]]

Show[plot[11], Table[plot[i], {i, 1, 10}]]
```

Comment: Did your edit solve your problem?  BTW, I tried running your code and ran into many undefined parameters / plots.  If you still have a question, please edit your code so that people can run it.

Comment: ps. Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Hi Josh, your use of `BlockRandom` around a `RandomReal` will basically reseed the generator, which means you will get the same result for all samples if you call it before every use of `RandomReal`, which is probably not what you want. Try to call `SeedRandom` with a fixed seed once at the start of your program (outside the `For` loop) for reproduceability and then inside your loop call `RandomReal` freely to get different random samples.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to define g and R @Chrisk. Let g = 9.8 and R =1. I've updated in the code.

Comment: @ThiesHeidecke that worked! Thanks so much. That and defining fixed the generation of plots. Now I'm just having trouble showing all the plots on the same base plot, plot[11].

Comment: Just fixed it. Thanks both of you for the help. I'll bring the code up to date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because i think this will make your life easier with Mathematica in the future i did a few refactorings on your solution to make it more idiomatic and give you some ideas what simpler options you have sometimes to get your result. First the fully refactored code:

```
ODESolFromICs[{x0_, xd0_}] := NDSolve[
    {x''[t] == -(g/R) Sin[x[t]], x[0] == x0, x'[0] == xd0}
    , x, {t, 0, 15}, MaxSteps -> 20000
];

PlotSolution[sol_, col_] := ParametricPlot[
    Evaluate[{x[t], Derivative[1][x][t]} /. sol]
    , {t, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> col
];

plotoptions = {
    PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {-10, 10}},
    Frame -> True, 
    FrameLabel -> {"Displacement, \[Theta]", Row[{"Momentum, ", Subscript[P, \[Theta]]}]}, 
    PlotLabel -> "Phase Space of Approoximate Motion of A Vertical Plane Pendelum",
    ImageSize -> Large,
    AspectRatio -> Automatic
};

g = 9.8;
R = 1;
SeedRandom[1];(*choose a different number for a different randomized run*)

plots = Table[
    initialangle = If[i < 6,
        RandomReal[{-\[Pi], \[Pi]}](*5 initial condition displacements between-\[Pi] and \[Pi]*),
        First@RandomPoint[MeshRegion[{{-5}, {-\[Pi]}, {\[Pi]}, {5}}, Line[{1, 2}],Line[{3, 4}]}]](*5 initial condition displacements outside of-\[Pi] and \[Pi]*)
    ];
    initialmomentum = RandomReal[{-5, 5}];(*initial condition momentum=random number between-5 and 5*)
    theta = ODESolFromICs[{initialangle, initialmomentum}];
    PlotSolution[theta, RandomColor[]]
    , {i, 10}
];

Show[plots, plotoptions]
```

[image: Pendulum phase space plot]

Now for what is changed:

- First we factor out the ODE solving and plotting the solution into their own functions `ODESolFromICs` and `PlotSolution`. This reduces code duplication and makes the code more readable. Also we added a parameter to give a plot color to `ParametricPlot`. Same holds true for the initial conditions for `NDSolve`.
- `Array[plot,11];` is in general not needed as 'initialization', as the meaning of the expression `plot[5]` will be given by the `plot[5]=...` (see `Set` in the documentation) replacement rule. We don't have to declare those expression before we use them, essentially because they are recognized patterns instead of uninitialized variables. Also the semicolon will discard the result, which means the line doesn't have any lasting effect.
- We can replace the `For` loop by a `Table` which iterates `i` from 1 to 10 and save the resulting list of `plots`. This replaces the previous different `plot[i]` expressions.
- We don't need a `plot[11]` expression that just holds the plot options we want, instead we can save those in a list and apply them at the end when we call `Show`. Directly giving those options to `Show` would also work.
- We can move in the `If[i<6,...]` to just influence the initial conditions, which makes the code easier to understand

Hope this helps! :)